# iText pdfReader Not Releasing File in ColdFusion 2018

Tags: java, coldfusion, itext, coldfusion-2018

I am upgrading to ColdFusion 2018.  iText routines that I use to convert and rotate PDFs,  the pdfReader puts locks on the file that do not release when the page is done.

I have tried adding a `close()` method to my code.  (It was not needed on the pdfReader in Release 11.)

```
<cfscript>

reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( "test.pdf" );

reader.close();

inStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileReader").init("test2.pdf");

inStream.close();

</cfscript>
```

I would expect to be able to rename or delete both files when the supplied script is ran, but only the inStream file (`test2.pdf`) can be.  The reader file (`test.pdf`) is locked by the system.

Comment: I get the same result.  Some internal (CF) voodoo must be holding onto a reference.  To work around it, pass in an inputstream (or RandomAccessFileOrArray) instead of file name. When finished with the reader, close() the stream. That works.  *was not needed on the pdfReader in Release 11* Still best to close things explicitly, even if not technically needed.

Comment: Which version of iText is that anyway? It must at least be 10 years old, probably older...

Comment: Thank you!  I think that will solve my issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert"? What kind of source are you starting with?

Answer (score 2):

Using the suggestions above, I think the following solution will work.

```
<cfscript>

    fkeys = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream");
    lKeyStoreFileStream = createObject("java", "java.io.BufferedInputStream").init(fkeys.init("test.pdf"));    

    reader = createObject("java", "com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader").init( lKeyStoreFileStream );

    lKeyStoreFileStream.close();
    fkeys.close();

    reader.close();

</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an older Java plugin, just use the native `cfpdf`.

```
<cfpdf action="transform" source="myPDF.pdf" rotation="90" name="outPDF">
```

There is a ton of other functionality available to this tag. https://cfdocs.org/cfpdf

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=eca41ba2-22f2-41f2-a205-0c2d3aafe91c/ca3873c8-4d4b-4cfc-8e64-6c4ceb825717/9861993d-7db3-43ee-882f-681a1aa498d4.cfm

Comment: I could be wrong, but got the impression it's existing code that might not be feasible to update .. Agreed a lot of stuff is possible using newer tags, though CF might still be using that lib beneath the hood if they're still bundling it with 2018 ;-).

Comment: I actually don't know what library `cfpdf` is using. Though I would hope that if they are still using iText, they'd have upgraded it to a newer version. The one using the `lowagie` namespace is pretty old, isn't it? Regardless, I still think that, in general, it would probably be worth the effort to refactor code that is using out-of-date libraries, especially if already editing code that is touching those libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not against refactoring, assuming it's feasible (not sure how extensive the code is). Just trying to help get their code running in the interim.   *I would hope that if they are still using iText, they'd have upgraded it to a newer version. The one using the lowagie namespace is pretty old, isn't it?* I don't know what it uses either, but the fact that the lib can still be loaded on a brand new install of 2018 isn't an encouraging sign... :-/

Comment: @Ageax Very true.